# Change color of a word in html

Tags: html

I have a `.html` document that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Change color</title>
  <style>
   .colortext {
     color: red; 
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>bla bla lbla <span class="colortext">the</span>, 
 the balfds of .</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

In this document I give to `the` a red color. But how should I go in order to change color of every `the`in my huge text? Is there a way to change color in order not to write

> `<span class="colortext">`

for **every** word, I need?

Comment: No the only way to change `the` to red in every instance is to add the span around it with that `colortext` class, if you want to do it programmatically you would use javascript to parse the string and add the span around the word for every instance it found

Comment: @Enjayy        Thank you for your comment. I got it. Can you show a little example of javascript using, please? If no, so no..

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to do this. I am not writing the whole code just giving you hints. Get by this var code = document.getElementById("demo") or ByTagName or ByName or any method. Details: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp . then replace value "the" with '<span class="colortext">the</span>' using javascript replace method. Details: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes with only HTML and CSS that is the only way.

Comment: Yes you can do with javascript! Try to search for "the" through the document and replace with <span class="colortext">the</span>. I can write a test if you need. Give it a try!

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/string-replace-javascript Here is a good article

Comment: As for deal , I'm using c++ for finding a big occurances of words. When I dind them ,I can take them and put in some box ,for example, `<span class>`. That's wht it doesn't matter which language use,if you say, I need to put around an every word, so...
But,what if I use: `<font color="red">the</font>`?

Comment: <font> tag is not supported anymore. But yes you can add the  <span class="colortext"></span> around every "the" word.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
<font color="red">the</font>
```

Comment: Really? can you show the whole example , how it should look ,I mean with my document, please?

Comment: it would just avoid the redundant css code and you can specify red color for each 'the' @X21

Comment: I got you, but can you show it ? where should put your answer. Sorry, I'm from c++ and don't html things yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use javascript to achieve this you can use regex like so.

**HTML**

```
<p id="sentence">bla bla lbla the, 
 the balfds of .</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
var sentence = document.getElementById('sentence');
var text = sentence.textContent;

var replaceWord = text.replace(/\bthe\b/g,"<span class='colortext'>$&
</span>")

sentence.innerHTML = replaceWord;
```